# How to define npm start scripts of package.json in react project on win10 when using dotenv to read .env file?

Tags: reactjs, npm, path, environment-variables, port

I'm tryin to run a React program(originally developed on mac), and in the package.json file, the code I got for "scripts" is like this:

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "set PORT=XXXX dotenv -e .env.local && react-app-rewired start",
   ......
}
```

in which xxx represents the port number.

When I tried to run this program via npm start on win, the error "Error: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined"
kept popping out. I wonder if anyone knows how to correctly write a command here for running on mac, cuz if I removed the '&&' signal, the npm run start could still work without errors but the website just won't show and the program didn't seem to be running either. Also, I'm pretty sure that the .env.local is provided and included in the program.

Could anyone also briefly explain the difference when running this kind of script on win comparing to mac?

Thanks!

Comment: Plus I'm pretty sure that there's no other bug in the program itself cuz if could be successfully run on mac

Comment: The difference is in the shell; `&&` runs the second command if the first succeeds. If you’re not running a reasonable shell on Windows you’ll need to convert it to whatever shell you’re running.

Comment: Thanks, but I wonder if including the dotenv -e .env.local will exert any effect on the command, since I thought the command I had right now for win is correct but the program just won't start.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-cli

Comment: Cool it helps! In this case I assume that I would need to add another '&&' before dotenv -e .env.local in the script here, but when I npm ran the code it still reminds me 'command failed' without any specific log details...Does anyone have ideas about the code here? The program itself doesn't have bugs for compiling and building.

Comment: The .env file is under the root or the project directory, could it be related incorrectly refering to the .env path in this command and thus the compiler could not find it? But I tried adding   \\"   before and after the .env.local path, it just doesn't make any difference.